# Block devices is not visible from aws console

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services

there is an block device (xvdb) whic is 30GB.

it is not existing in aws console so i cannot get image (copy) of this block.

is there anyway to get copy of this block with aws management console?

[image: ssh command result vs aws console result]

Comment: what is your OS, what is your AMI ( amazon AMI or custom bundle), what steps did you made previously?

Comment: my os is ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heuristics suggest that this is an m3.large or r3.large instance, and `/dev/xvdb` is your 32GB SSD *ephemeral volume*, also known as an instance store volume.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html

If this is true, you definitely need to familiarize yourself with ephemeral disks before you continue using it for whatever you are using it for.  They don't appear in the console because they are not EBS volumes, and can't be snapshotted for the same reason.

Importantly, you should not *need* to snapshot an ephemeral disk, because you should never store anything important on one.

They are intended for transient/temporary use only, such as for temporary files or swap space, because unlike EBS, they are not redundant.  They are automatically wiped if you stop the instance, and are blank if you start it back up again (unlike EBS).  If the host machine the object instance running on experiences a hardware failure, their data will also go away.

They do have their advantages.  They're physically inside the host machine, not across the LAN like EBS.  They have no IOPS charge like magnetic EBS (again, good for swap and temp files).  Also, they are free... But as you can see, they are quite different from EBS volumes.